# How to prove that the operator $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ exists?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A:H^1(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the operator given by $Aw=w_x$, where $w_x$ denotes the weak derivative of $w$.

I need help to prove that $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded for all $\lambda >0$.

To prove the existence, the first thing that I tried to show was $\ker(\lambda I-A)=0$. Notice that

$$w\in\ker(\lambda I - A)\Rightarrow\int_\mathbb{R}w(\varphi'+\lambda\varphi)dx=0\;\;\;\forall\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$$

however I don't know how to conclude (maybe there is some way to apply the du Bois-Reymond lemma).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an explicit expression for $[(\lambda I - A)^{-1} f](t)$, namely $g(t) := \int_t^{\infty} e^{\lambda (t-s)} f(s) ds$. Indeed, applying $(\lambda I - A)$ to $g$ shows $[(\lambda I - A) g](t) = f(t)$. If $f \in L_2$ then $g \in H^1$ is fairly evident.